# Why was Vader talking about "Rebel transmissions" in Episode IV when he saw the data tape being passed in Rogue One?

Tags: star-wars, rogue-one

In *A New Hope*, Darth Vader on Tantive IV says: “several rebel transmissions were beamed aboard this ship from rebel spies…”.

Except that, in Rogue One, we see that the plans were NOT beamed onto Tantive IV - it was docked inside Mon Calamari flagship, and the plans were physically sneaker-netted through a door from one rebel to another as a data tape - **witnessed by Darth Vader!**.

Vader clearly knew what the tape was from the novelization:

> The voice of a stormtrooper spoke to him through his comlink. “A data tape was recorded on the bridge just before we boarded. No sign of it here.”
>
> *[...]*
>
> The security door opened a mere crack and rebel hands shoved the tape through. Vader reached through life and matter and air and by will alone he *pulled*. He fueled his will with rage and fear and need. It was enough to tear the rebel from the door and drop him at Vader’s feet.
>
> But it was not enough to claim the tape.
>
> He grasped the rebel sprawled before him by the throat, lifted him and stared at him through bloody lenses. “Where,” Vader demanded, “are they taking it?”

**Is there an explanation for this discrepancy?**

Comment: I asked Hidalgo personally. [His response wasn't helpful](https://twitter.com/pablohidalgo/status/811399628608311297)

Comment: Okay, looks he's taking a break from answering *Rogue One* questions until January. *[sigh]*. That's what I get for tweeting before reading

Comment: Maybe it was a setup. "...transmissions were beamed-" "No, they weren't beamed, they were handed-" *Vader cuts off Rebel's hands* "You were saying?" Vader likes his jokes, but not all of them work out.

Comment: They'll probably retcon this in the Digitally Remastered Digitally Remastered Special Collector's Edition being released some time during the next years using the power of CGI to fix this discrepancy.

Comment: What if the transmissions beamed to the Tantive IV were not the Death Star plans? My speculation: the Death Star plans were brought aboard the Tantive IV and the Tantive IV escapes. The ship then attempts to spoof itself as another vessel coming from anywhere but Scarif on its way to Alderaan. But Vader correctly identifies the Tantive IV *because* rebel communications were sent to the ship (any communication will do).

Comment: A continuity error? Surely not.

Comment: There's certain ambiguity that Vader even saw the data disk. The first rebel soldier carrying it was right by the stuck door at the back of the rebel team. He may have seen it when he passes the first door and sees the rebel running and stumbling however.

Comment: Because Episode IV was written 40 years ago, and things have been retconned/fleshed out a lot since then.

Comment: Even though he's more machine now than man, he is still only human, and prone to make mistakes. One might as well ask why Vader let the plans slip from his grasp at all.

Comment: Occam's Razor: the Rogue One writers forgot about that line in Ep. IV.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Either he thought *Tantive IV* was an escape vessel, not its own ship, or he didn't see the data tape

Pablo Hidalgo has been asked this question several times on Twitter ([once](https://twitter.com/pablohidalgo/status/811399628608311297) by yours truly), but his most helpful response is probably [this long](https://twitter.com/pablohidalgo/status/812062296583245824) Twitter thread from late December 2016; in it, Hidalgo pretty much confirms that this is an inherent contradiction between the film and the novelization:

[image]

> **@TheDonkeyDrip** "As particle bolts shot toward him, he watched a data tape pass between desperate soldiers."
>
> **@pablohidalgo** Yeah, it has the stormtrooper tell him as well. I was referencing the movie.

He does provide a rationalization for this earlier in the conversation:

[image]

> **@TheDonkeyDrip** but then why is he so adamant about "beamed transmissions" if he saw the physical data tape?
>
> **@pablohidalgo** Did he see it?
>
> **@TheDonkeyDrip** The official novelization says he did.
>
> **@pablohidalgo** Novel also has him view the Tantive as an escape vessel of the cruiser. Cuts on either side of semantics.

The passage he references is probably this one from the novel:

> "Where," Vader demanded, "are they taking it?"
>
> The reply was a strangled whisper. "Away from here," the rebel said. "Away from you."
>
> Vader clenched his gloved hand until the man's neck snapped. Then he tossed the body aside. He activated his comlink and barked to his stormtroopers, "*Find their escape vessel*."
>
> <sup>*Rogue One: A Star Wars Story - Official Novelization* Epilogue</sup>

So you have two options:

1. **He didn't see the tape**. Wouldn't be the first time a novelization got something wrong; they're normally based on early drafts of the script, so perhaps this was an error that just got caught too late to fix in both versions. As [Hidalgo reminds us](https://twitter.com/pablohidalgo/status/812342846011252736):

   [image]

   > Think of a novelization as an adaptation of canonical events.
   >
   > Because of how and when they're written, there will always be differences.
   >
   > In cases of contradiction, defer to the movie.
2. **He didn't see *Tantive IV* as an independent vessel**. This is an admittedly weak rationalization, but if *Tantive IV* is an extension of the *Profundity*, then Vader's statement makes perfect sense.

Comment: Also, I now feel really bad for Hidalgo. This is what he has to deal with all day. At least he's got [a sense of humour](https://twitter.com/pablohidalgo/status/812089734516215808) about it

Comment: In Star Wars land, ironically, novelizations are typically far superior to script's final versions (where details differ) - that was true for ROTS and TFA, at least. Absent more updates from Hidalgo, this seems as good as an answer i'll ever get, so you get the accept.

Comment: @DVK-in-exile You won't get an argument from me; I do wish they could be more in-sync sometimes, but then I also don't want to wait six months to a year for the novel, so here we are

Comment: while it wouldn't ever happen due to unlikely prospect for good profit margins, an *ideal* solution would be a 2.0 version of novelization based on latest on-screen script, released separately.

Answer (score 38):

There certainly *were* transmissions from Rebel spies on the planet's surface to a Rebel ship in orbit.

It is true that the transmission was to the rebel flagship, and from there it was brought on a data tape to the blockade runner in one of the flagship's hangar bays.

There are a couple of plausible explanations:

1. Vader simply does not care about such details. There was a rebel transmission, and the data from that transmission ended up on the blockade runner. His goal is to intimidate the Rebel officer, not provide an accurate technical report.
2. Vader is angry with the failure of the Imperial forces on the planet's surface to prevent the transmission. It would be in character for him to focus on this instead of

> his own failure to stop the Rebels from handing the plans through the airlock

because as we all know, Anakin/Vader is not very good at taking responsibility for his actions.

Comment: I agree. Vader most probably knew the data was originally transmitted, although it was later saved on a physical device. It's still confusing, though, that he says "beamed aboard this ship" when the transmissions were reportedly received by the Mon Calamari flagship. He must have known the difference between those two.

Comment: @Essen Knowing and caring are two different things...

Comment: "It is true that the transmission was to the rebel flagship, and from there it was brought on a data tape to the blockade runner in one of the flagship's hangar bays." Excellent point. +1

Comment: Blaming Anakin always gets an upvote from me :)

Comment: I agree with this answer that this is a distinction that Vader simply would not care about while slaughtering rebel scum, nor is it even consequential. It is almost as silly as asking "Why did Vader end this sentence with a preposition?"